# Scheduling algorithm in ROS

Tags: linux, scheduling, ros

How does linux schedule the execution of nodes in ROS? 
Does ROS has any specific scheduling algorithm?

How does ROS work on Linux?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://answers.ros.org/question/319507/how-does-ros-schedule-nodes/

Comment: So basically complety fair scheduling algorithm is used to schedule nodes

Answer (score 0):

ROS node is completely same as any other process running on user space in Linux for scheduler.